# Change transmission fluid

Tags: nissan, fluid, sunny

I have a 1997 Nissan FB14 Sunny with a GA15 engine (Japanese specs). I want to change the automatic transmission fluid. Can anyone tell me how much Quarts it will take?
I don't want to overfill and cause damages.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: You need to find the filling procedure for your car.  You can't just empty the old fluid and add a specific amount of new fluid.  Often on Autos, you will only get about a third of the total fluid out when you empty the sump.